# Facebook access token without Login Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can we get the Facebook user access token without prompting to login page. Isn't it enough having App Id and App Secret to get the token. I have tried according to the Facebook API documentation. But it prompts to login screen if you are not already logged in in the browser.

**This is what document says,**

**User Access Token** – *The user token is the most commonly used type of token. This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf. User access tokens are generally obtained via a login dialog and require a person to permit your app to obtain one.*

Comment: No. To get a ***user*** access token, the user must indicate consent.

Comment: So every time when we need to make a API call we have to logged in to our facebook account (which is connected with related facebook app)

Comment: IIRC there are endpoints for refreshing tokens once they are acquired.

Comment: You are right. I might be able to refresh token via exchanging old token. Thanks!

Comment: without user interaction, you cannot generate or refresh a user token. please read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/